Why does the buildscript block have to be at the top of the build configuration file?
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.7.7"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"

    }
}

plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.1" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "8.1.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.23" apply false
}

This is the code from top-level build.gradle.
If you move the buildscript block down in the code above, the error below occurs and the build does not work.
Why do I need to put the buildscript block at the top and what exactly causes the error?
I solved it by putting the buildscript block as the top block.

The error is probably just a Groovy limitation since kts based gradle files don't care.
However, you don't need to use the buildscript block (the old way) at all, just add it as a plugin (the "new" way):
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.1" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "8.1.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.23" apply false
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs") version "2.7.7" apply false
}

If you only use Kotlin you can use id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin") instead.
